# Nested forms not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have two models (Bcase and C_entry) and I am trying to get 10 blank c_entry fields on each Bcase creation form!

What I did is following:

Models:

**bcase.rb**

```
class Bcase < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :c_entries, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :c_entries        
end
```

**c_entry.rb**

```
class CEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bcase
end
```

**bcase_controller.rb**

```
  def new
        @bcase = Bcase.new
        10.times {@bcase.c_entries.build}
  end

def bcase_params
    params.require(:bcase).permit(:pimp_id, :comment_text, :status, c_entries_attributes:[:id, :description, :bcase_id])
end
```

**form** (gets rendered in bcase -> new.html.erb)

```
<%= simple_form_for :bcase, url: bcase_path do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
        <% f.simple_fields_for :c_entries do |entry| %> 
        <%= entry.input :description %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But if I open the view on localhost in my browser the form is empty. I tested everything and I know that the everything is working for the bcase attributes but not for the nested attributes. If I try to initialize only 1 object instead if 10 with `@bcase.c_entries.build` nothing changes, still doenst show anything nested. Further I tried to create c_entries via rails console and that worked. I used the command `Bcase.first.c_entries.build` aswell.

EDIT: Okay, the problem is solved but now my view shows only 1 entry instead of 10! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2:

**Rake routes**

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
     protocols GET    /protocols(.:format)              protocols#index
               POST   /protocols(.:format)              protocols#create
  new_protocol GET    /protocols/new(.:format)          protocols#new
 edit_protocol GET    /protocols/:id/edit(.:format)     protocols#edit
      protocol GET    /protocols/:id(.:format)          protocols#show
               PATCH  /protocols/:id(.:format)          protocols#update
               PUT    /protocols/:id(.:format)          protocols#update
               DELETE /protocols/:id(.:format)          protocols#destroy
         pimps GET    /                                 pimps#index
      new_pimp GET    /new(.:format)                    pimps#new
     edit_pimp GET    /:id/edit(.:format)               pimps#edit
          pimp GET    /:id(/.:format)                   pimps#show
               POST   /(.:format)                       pimps#create
               PUT    /:id(.:format)                    pimps#update
               PATCH  /:id(.:format)                    pimps#update
               DELETE /:id(.:format)                    pimps#destroy
   new_mepager GET    /:pimp_id/onepager/new(.:format)  mepagers#new
  edit_mepager GET    /:pimp_id/onepager/edit(.:format) mepagers#edit
       mepager GET    /:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)      mepagers#show
create_mepager POST   /:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)      mepagers#create
               PUT    /:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)      mepagers#update
               PATCH  /:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)      mepagers#update
               DELETE /:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)      mepagers#destroy
     new_bcase GET    /:pimp_id/bcase/new(.:format)     bcases#new
    edit_bcase GET    /:pimp_id/bcase/edit(.:format)    bcases#edit
         bcase GET    /:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)         bcases#show
  create_bcase POST   /:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)         bcases#create
               PUT    /:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)         bcases#update
               PATCH  /:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)         bcases#update
               DELETE /:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)         bcases#destroy
```

**Simple_form_for**

```
<%= simple_form_for bcase_path(@pimp) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

<%= simple_fields_for :c_entries do |ff| %>
<div class="form-actions">
<%= ff.input :description, label: false %>
<% end %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**bcase_controller.rb**

```
def setall
   @pimp = Pimp.find(params[:pimp_id])
   @bcase = @pimp.bcase
end
```

**Error with @bcase in simple_form_for**

```
NoMethodError in Bcases#new 
Showing c:/Users/Public/Documents/Sites/improvement/app/views/bcases/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised: 

undefined method `bcases_path' for #<#<Class:0x53efbc0>:0x4d195d0>
```

EDIT3:

Did some more testing and included after

```
<p><%= "Nr of c-entries = #{@bcase.c_entries.size}" %></p>
```

What gives me `10` back the lines

```
<%= @bcase.c_entries.each do |entry| %>
<%= entry.description %>
<% end %>
```

And that shows me 10 empty entries! So they are there, I just cant see them somehow!

```
[#<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 1, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 2, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 3, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 4, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 5, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 6, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 7, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 8, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 9, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 10, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

EDIT4:

Included now `bcases_path` into my routes for debugging. Now my form_for works with @bcase but that doesnt solve the problems I have.

EDIT5:

It somehow works with

```
<%= @bcase.c_entries.each do |hallo| %>
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :c_entries, hallo do |fff| %>
    <%= fff.input :description %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Probably cause the c_entries are specified. But this solution doesnt look so lean! Is it possible to specify this somehow in the bcase controller?

Comment: It looks good. Sure it is not a typo, you write `desribtion` with a `b`?

Comment: Oh, well noticed sir. I changed the column name from describtion to description lately and forgot to change it in the forms and controller! I corrected that now but it still doenst work. I cant explain myself whats missing. Looked into various guides and its not even much code so the space for mistakes it so small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it! You forgot the `=` in the `<%=`. So the block will execute correctly, but will not be added to the form.

So write

```
<%= simple_form_for @bcase do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :c_entries do |entry| %> 
      <%= entry.input :description %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Okay, but now I've got the problem that its only showing 1 entry and not all 10!

Comment: In your first comment you said it was working perfectly, so I guess it was not :) Instead of writing `:bcase`, you should probably refer to the instance variable. So I updated my answer. For debugging you could include something like `<p><%= "Nr of c-entries = #{@bcase.c_entries.count}" %></p>`.

Comment: Yea, sorry I was so overwelmed that I saw the form fields :D I totally forgot to check if its working for multiple entries. And its not :( Since my bcase model is nested into another model I changed the `<%= simple_form_for @bcase do |f| %>` to `<%= simple_form_for @bcase(@pimp) do |f| %>` but that didnt change anything. The debug function that you provided wont work, because the c_entries are not saved at that state. Is there a way to make it work to count non saved entries? Big thanks!

Comment: Use `size` instead of count (i mix them up). If you write just `@bcase`, does it work? If you need a nested route, you should write `simple_form_for [@pimp, @bcase]` (or reverse them, do not know the order by heart). I would expect the `@bcase(@pimp)` to throw an error, that is not even ruby :)

Comment: Ok buddy. It's not working with `simple_form_for [@pimp, @bcase]` because my routes are a little customized. But bcase_path(@pimp) should do it I guess (but I might be wrong ;)). The debug method shows the right amount of objects (10). So it has to be the view, right?

Comment: Buddy?? Type `rake routes` to find your path names. At the moment I am not sure you have the correct object for your form (the debugging is for `@bcase`, which probably is _not_ the object of the form). Can you show me the complete `simple_form_for` line? First try with just `@bcase` and then fix the url.

Comment: I know my path names. And its the right path and its working for this I used it at different occasions and it always works fine. I even created a test object and it gets showns properly. The only thing that I dont get to see are the entries. Nevertheless I will post my `rake routes` and the error I get if I just use @bcase. And my simple_form_for line of course!

Comment: Afaik your simple_form line is wrong: you never give it the `@bcase` variable. Ideally, when you write `simple_form_for @bcase` rails will change the path depending on whether `@bcase` is new or existed already (create vs update). But afaik you are now just handling new objects, so you should write something like `simple_form_for @bcase, url: bcase_path(@pimp)`.

Comment: Yay, thats it! Now its working without my workaround! Thank you so much!